# Regex to search between two consecutive occurrences of a string, the second which may be optional

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to set up a regex in Java that would work for a 0 to infinite-occurrence input scenario. What that means is that the most basic input could be:

```
Heading 1
   SubheadingA: SomethingX
   SubheadingB: SomethingY
   SubheadingC: SomethingZ
```

and I want to find the value next to SubheadingB under Heading 1, i.e., SomethingY.

This may look like the following and the regex wouldn't match anything:

```
Heading 1
   SubheadingA: SomethingX
   SubheadingC: SomethingZ
```

or it may look like this and return SomethingY:

```
Heading 1
   SubheadingA: SomethingX
   SubheadingB: SomethingY
   SubheadingC: SomethingZ

Heading 2
   SubheadingA: SomethingU
   SubheadingB: SomethingV
   SubheadingC: SomethingW
```

I thought I had the solution with this regex:

```
Heading\s+(1).*?SubheadingB:\s+(.*?)\n.*?(Heading)?
```

However, this still returns a match in the following situation:

```
Heading 1
   SubheadingA: SomethingX
   SubheadingC: SomethingZ

Heading 2
   SubheadingA: SomethingU
   SubheadingB: SomethingV
   SubheadingC: SomethingW

Heading 3
   SubheadingA: SomethingR
   SubheadingB: SomethingS
   SubheadingC: SomethingT
```

SomethingV is returned since "Heading 1" was found, followed by "SubheadingB" under "Heading 2" and "Heading 3" which is not what I want.

This might even be expanded to a much longer example where I just need to search between "Heading 1" and the very next occurrence of "Heading" for that particular Subheading and its value:

```
Heading -1
   SubheadingB: SomethingBB
   SubheadingC: SomethingCC

Heading 0
   SubheadingA: SomethingDD
   SubheadingB: SomethingEE
   SubheadingC: SomethingFF

Heading 1
   SubheadingA: SomethingX
   SubheadingB: SomethingY
   SubheadingC: SomethingZ

Heading 2
   SubheadingA: SomethingGG
   SubheadingB: SomethingHH

Heading 3
   SubheadingA: SomethingJJ
   SubheadingB: SomethingKK
   SubheadingC: SomethingLL
```

I would still like it to return SomethingY or nothing at all if "Heading 1 -> SubheadingB -> Whatever value" isn't found.

What could I use to specify an occurrence of Heading after Heading 1 that may or may not occur? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Forgot the greedy matcher between the newline and optional Heading. I use newline because there might be a space in SomethingY, so the regex may be capturing from:

```
SubheadingB: Something Y
```

and should return "Something Y".

Comment: I don't know if it works with java, but have a try with: `Heading 1\s+(?:(?!\bHeading\b)[\s\S])*SubheadingB:\h*\K.+$`

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to skip over another `Heading`. For this you can set up lines between to not start by use of a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Sample as a Java String **with** flag `MULTILINE` and **without** `DOTALL`.

```
"^Heading +(1).*(?:\\r?\\n(?! *Heading).*)*?\\r?\\n.*?SubheadingB: *(.*)"
```

See these demos at regex101: [[1]](https://regex101.com/r/FwS18I/2) [[2]](https://regex101.com/r/FwS18I/1) [[3]](https://regex101.com/r/FwS18I/3)  (non Java)

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I need. Still trying to understand how the negative lookahead works and what exactly the carriage return is doing with the newline, but thanks!

Comment: @Pazow The negative lookahead checks after each newline if there is not substr `Heading` ahead with optional amount of space. So this won't skip over lines starting with `Heading`. You can drop the `\r?` if your files are not using `CRLF`. Glad it helped!

Comment: Is there a way I could avoid zero-length matches in this? For example, https://regex101.com/r/FwS18I/4

Comment: @Pazow Sure, you can require an `\S` (non white-space). See [this updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/FwS18I/6).

Comment: Ah now this is perfect! Thanks so much for your help and educational response!

Comment: Just a follow-up: how would this work if I had multiple groups (not a predefined number) that I wanted to capture? In the example, SomethingY, SomethingYY and SomethingYYY should be returned: https://regex101.com/r/FwS18I/8

Comment: @Pazow Maybe something like [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/FwS18I/10) by use of [`\G` which chains matches](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html). Such pattern will be considerably slower. There are probably more elegant solutions.